# How to add unequal intervals to date

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I created  shift timings like this

```
library(lubridate)    
date1 <- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 05:30:00",tz = "US/Eastern")   

shifts2<- lapply(0:14, function(x){
  lapply(c(0,270,480,960), function(y){
    interval((date1+days(x)+minutes(y)), (date1+days(x)+minutes(y+480)))
  })
})
```

Here is my output

> ```
> [1] 2000-01-01 05:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 2000-01-01 10:00:00 EST--2000-01-01 18:00:00 EST
>
> [[3]]
> [1] 2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST
>
> [[4]]
> [1] 2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST--2000-01-02 05:30:00 EST
> ```

I am able to add fixed 480 minutes to each shift.

Now i want to add 480 minutes to 1st shift , 600 minutes to next shift etc.
Basically I want to add unequal length shift timings.

My expected output is:

```
2000-01-01 05:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST 
2000-01-01 10:00:00 EST--2000-01-01 17:30:00 EST 
2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST 
2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST--2000-01-02 05:30:00 EST
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: 2000-01-01 05:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST  


 2000-01-01 10:00:00 EST--2000-01-01 17:30:00 EST


 2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST


2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST--2000-01-02 05:30:00 EST    Four shifts

Comment: You know you can only upvote one answer? You accepted my answer and then LocoGris answer, so mine got unaccepted. If this is what you intended to do then I've said nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure if I get your question correctly. Your expected output differs from what you describe in your question.

From your expected output I derived these shifts: `c(480, 450, 480, 480)`

```
shifts <- lapply(0:14, function(x){
  mapply(function(y,z){
    interval((date1+days(x)+minutes(y)), (date1+days(x)+minutes(y+z)))
  }, y = c(0,270,480,960), z = c(480, 450, 480, 480), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
})


> shifts[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] 2000-01-01 05:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST

[[2]]
[1] 2000-01-01 10:00:00 EST--2000-01-01 17:30:00 EST

[[3]]
[1] 2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST

[[4]]
[1] 2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST--2000-01-02 05:30:00 EST
```

So I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I think I like your approach better than mine. Only a comment: is it `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` necessary?

Comment: yes, it's necessary. Otherwise it coerces it to a weird vector.

Comment: again someone who doesn't know that you can only accept 1 answer xD I don't know how often my answers get accepted and then immediatly unaccepted.

Comment: I have would chosen yours. Just upvote mine or even nothinh

Comment: Many just don't know, so I told him. Upvoted yours, too. It works, too, and you were faster. ^^

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(lubridate)    
date1 <- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 05:30:00",tz = "US/Eastern")   
intervalsMin <- c(0,270,480,960)
incrementalMin <- c(480,720,960,1440)
shifts

2<- lapply(0:14, function(x){
      lapply(1:(length(intervalsMin)), function(y){
        interval((date1+days(x)+minutes(intervalsMin[y])), (date1+days(x)+minutes(incrementalMin[y])))
      })
    })
    shifts2[[1]]
    #[[1]]
#[1] 2000-01-01 05:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST

#[[2]]
#[1] 2000-01-01 10:00:00 EST--2000-01-01 17:30:00 EST

#[[3]]
#[1] 2000-01-01 13:30:00 EST--2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST

#[[4]]
#[1] 2000-01-01 21:30:00 EST--2000-01-02 05:30:00 EST
```